# Would it be more appropriate to use a type="tel" attribute for a postcode rather than ="text"?

Tags: html, forms

As the title says.

Would this would be better than type = number or text because of the fact that it automatically only allows user input of a number, rather than the user still being able to type in letters even when a constraint has been placed on the text.

Edit: I know that this is obviously not semantically and correct to do this as it is a different data type and also is not yet fully supported in browsers. But could it (in theory) be used to substitute text for a page that had really no server side interaction and is basically used as a 'example' for what the user should expect when filling in the postcode section of a form. This is considering the website user are also from the same country with the postcodes all being numbers.

"To be used for aesthetic display purposes only?"

Comment: A postcode... isn't a telephone number.

Comment: I know that! I meant if I was in one specific country where the postcode is a standard 4 digits - ####. 
@Giancarlo PSK This is what I have already (expression), but with this the user can still enter alphabet characters until submit, when they are then alerted. I was going to try an keep them from entering alphabet characters in the first place like "tel" does. But as you said with them not really being supported yet, it is a good idea just to keep it how it is. Or is there another constraint I can put on "text" to keep it only numbers?

Comment: Well, my point is that you should never use an element to represent something it categorically is not, even if it seems as though it could accept values in a certain format, e.g. 4-digit postcodes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Eventually, down the road it may cause a problem somewhere or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not be appropriate.  tel is for telephone numbers.  And some postcodes contain characters.  (for instance:  Nova Scotia - B4V 2K4 )

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use either, they are really not supported yet (tel and number).
Instead, I'd create an input text, and check the format by using a regular expression (or a list of a limited range of postcodes if you need so).

hope it helps.